# how to match one word or another, within a single line, with sed

Tags: regex, sed, cpu-word, match

For this command `xwininfo -id 0x8a00004 |grep "Absolute\|Width\|Height"` I have this output

```
Absolute upper-left X:  44
Absolute upper-left Y:  53
Width: 999
Height: 698
```

by using a single sed command, I want it to become this:

```
nX=44
nY=53
nWidth=999
nHeight=698
```

My current code is this:

```
xwininfo -id 0x8a00004 |grep "Absolute\|Width\|Height" |sed -r 's".*([XY]):[[:blank:]]*(.*)"n\1=\2"'
```

I am aware that to match words with sed, I need to use `\bWordToMatch\b` on the expression, but I cannot find a way to put it where `([XY])` is on my command...
I am aware also that to match "one OR other" word, I need to use `\|`, that I cant guess either..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try following `sed`

```
sed -r 's/.*(X|Y|Width|Height)\s*:\s*([0-9]+)/n\1=\2/'
```

Comment: worked! I had to break the `[]` mind barrier; also the `|` was restricted by `()` (which I thought would not work..) thx!

Comment: In [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions), the parentheses and vertical bar [need to be escaped](http://superuser.com/a/112000/219226) like this: `\( \| \)`.

Comment: This answer uses the `-r` flag, equivalent to GNU `--regexp-extended`. No need to escape with `-r`, but the answer should say so.